# Call S4 function from within same object

Tags: r, function, oop, r-s4

I made this (simplified) S4 class:

```
setClass(
  Class = "WOW", 
  representation = representation(
    x = 'numeric',
    y = 'numeric'
  )

)

setGeneric("run", function(.Object, x, y, do) 
  standardGeneric("run") )

setGeneric("add", function(.Object, x, y, do) 
  standardGeneric("add") )


setMethod("add", signature("WOW"), function(.Object, x, y ) {
  return(x + y)
})


setMethod("run", signature("WOW"), function(.Object, x, y, do) {
  if (do == 'ADD') {
    print('ADDING')
    # --> RUN wow function
  }
})
```

I basically want to user to call the `run` function and tell it what to do (via the `do` parameter) with the two input numbers (`x` and `y`). So i the user says "ADD" it should call the `add` function and return the results to the `run` function. I know this can be done in python and java via self or this but how can this be done in R?

I figured out it could work calling `add(.Object, x, y)` but I cannot find any reference stating that this is the accepted way of doing so.

*(Obviously I could just add the number here in a single line of code so I don't need a function but my application is much more complex requiring a function to keep it neat)*

Comment: Can't quit follow, Maybe use `add` within `run`?

Comment: This does not suit an answer, but one alternative is to use `R6` classes, for which you could use the `self$` within public and private declarations.

Comment: @NelsonGon I indeed could declare the `add` function within `run` however in my original code I do have a lot of functions I need to call which would make it messy